# NHibernate self-referencing many-to-many without "up reference"

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I want to realize a "role" structure using NHibernate (**not** *Fluent*, I like XML mappings...). It works so far with a role being a set of permissions (enum) being mapped (as strings).

But now the next requirement is that roles need a generic method of determining what other roles they can grant users.

So, an "Admin role" would be allowed to grant any other role to a user. A "Moderator role" would only be allowed to e.g. assign the role "Super user" to a user, and a "User role" wouldn't have any roles that it can grant.

I thought that the simplest method would be to create another set, this time of type `Role` to the existing `Role` as such:

```
public class Role
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Role> GrantableRoles { get; set; }

    public Role()
    {
        Permissions = new HashedSet<Permission>();
        GrantableRoles = new HashedSet<Role>();
        Name = string.Empty;
    }

    public virtual bool HasPermission(Permission permission_)
    {
        return Permissions.Contains(permission_);
    }

    public virtual bool CanGrant(Role role_)
    {
        return GrantableRoles.Contains(role_);
    }
}
```

The problem is: How do I map this in the `Role.hbm.xml` file? I guess it should be a `many-to-many` relation, but as far as I know, that type always requires an "up reference", that is: *That a role knows by which roles it can be granted*.

This is an information that is both unnecessary and (imho) not something a role *should* know.

That's why I need some kind of `many-to-many`, but without the referenced entity knowing about where it is referenced from.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really not as hard as I originally thought. It can be done using a `set`:

```
<set name="GrantableRoles" table="role_grants" lazy="false">
    <key column="grantingRole"/>
    <many-to-many class="Core.Model.Role,Core" column="grantableRole" />
</set>
```

Note: `lazy=false` was done so the grantable roles are always present, which may only be relevant in my case, because I have to save the roles in the `HttpSession` of the application, and if I were to do that with `lazy=true`, the `NHibernateSession` would expire every now and then.